# Symfony2 form entity style each option differently (collapse)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity field (visitors) in a form. I would like to highlight a person according to its status.

```
->add('visitors', 'entity', array(
     'class'     => "T2m3Bundle:Person",
     'multiple'  => true,
     'property'  => 'entireName',
     'required'  => false,
)
```

I have a method `getStatus`, that returns 4 states. On every state I want to put different "style" in an option tag.

Here is the example:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Mary</option>
  <option value="2" class="alert alert-danger">John</option>
  <option value="3" class="alert alert-success">Peter</option>
  <option value="4" class="alert alert-warning">Robert</option>
</select>
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
{% for visitor in form.visitors %}
    {% set index = visitor.vars.value %}
    {% set entity = form.visitors.vars.choices[index].data %}

        {% if entity.status == 1 %}
            {{ form_widget(visitor) }}
            <span class="alert alert-warning">{{ entity.entireName }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if entity.status == 2 %}
            {{ form_widget(visitor) }}
            <span class="alert alert-danger">{{ entity.entireName }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        ....
{% endfor %}
```

This example works for `'expanded' => true` but not for collapse type. I would be really thankful for an answer.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Expanded use this template with `form_widget(...)`:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded -%}
<div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
{%- for child in form %}
    {{- form_widget(child) -}}
    {{- form_label(child) -}}
{% endfor -%}
</div>
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

but I don't know how to render manually collapsed type, where there is no `{{- form_widget(...) -}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the twig choice widget : refer to [this link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) to find the according block. It's something like this

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {% if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif %}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}

{% block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}
            {# HERE we define the class based on the status #}
            {% if status is defined %}
                {% if status == 1 %}
                    {% set status_class = 'alert alert-warning' %}
                {% elseif status == 2 %}
                    {% set status_class = 'alert alert-danger' %}
                {% elseif ... %}
                    ....
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %} {% if status_class is defined %} class="{{ status_class }}" {% endif %} >{{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options %}
```

Finally in your template, call the widget like this :

```
{% for visitor in form.visitors %}
    {% set index = visitor.vars.value %}
    {% set entity = form.visitors.vars.choices[index].data %}

        {{ form_widget(visitor, {'status': entity.status}) }}
        ....
{% endfor %}
```

This is not tested, but should work. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The logic seems very good to me, but I have a problem that the form doesn't render something. It seems that it ignores `{{ form_widget(visitor, {'status': entity.status}) }}`, because there is no widget in the template. Is there some possibility to render each option?

Comment: you need to put the code I gave you in a template ! and call this template as a twig theme ! Refer to this link for [twig theming](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsymfony.com%2Fdoc%2Fcurrent%2Fcookbook%2Fform%2Fform_customization.html&ei=i8IxVOTII9DZaonSgMgJ&usg=AFQjCNFZIrC7DC5xxaTnuKpXDYlFQQ1Qsw&sig2=QZqzp2J4iUWzJ4db8gkv2w&bvm=bv.76802529,d.d2s)

Comment: Of course I did. imported template with `{% form_theme form 'MyBundle:Form:form_visitors_availability.html.twig' %}` inside my view. Cleared a cache, everything. The theme is good, but I can not find `form_widget` there.

Comment: But again there is no problem with a template, because otherwise it should work in the code that I wrote in the answer.